# show that $[n \sqrt{3}]$ is an approximate group

Tags: group-theory, additive-combinatorics

I have been reading about the notion of an [approximate group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_group).  These are subsets of groups that are still somewhat symmetric:

> $A \subseteq G$ is a $K$ - [approximate group](http://www.ams.org/notices/201205/rtx120500655p.pdf) if
>
> - it's symmetric $g \in A$ implies $g^{-1} \in A$
> - There exists $X \subset G$ with $|X| = K$ such that $A \cdot A \subset X\cdot A$

Let's try this definition out on example.  Let $G = \mathbb{Z}$ be an infinite group and $A = \{ [n\sqrt{3}]: n \in \mathbb{Z}\} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ be a subset. How many translates are needed to cover $A+A$?  It could be argued that:
$$ |A+A| < 4 |A| $$
(I think the number is 4, please correct me it's 3 or 5 or something).  However, these are not translates.

Here $[ \cdot ]$ is the [floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions).

My question is to find a constant $K$ such that $[\sqrt{3}\mathbb{Z}]\subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ is a $K$-approximate group.

Taking integer part turns out to be asymmetric, but it's still not that bad; doesn't fail the definition to egregiously.  However, let's try [rounding to the nearest integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding):

$$ [n]_1 =   [ n + 0.5 ]  $$

This is called "rounding half-up".  So we'd have $- [ \sqrt{3}\mathbb{Z}] = [\sqrt{3}\mathbb{Z}]$ is a symmetric set.

---

- Melvyn Nathanson [Every finite set of integers is an asymptotic approximate group](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.06478)

Comment: I don't think A is symmetric.

Comment: I haven't decided how I feel about that yet.  $A$ is still a subset of $\mathbb{Z}$, the sumset $A+A$ makes sense and we can can ask how many translates of $A$ are needed so that $A+A \subseteq X+A$.